# Showing a message in OpenGL screen is not working on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I have downloaded a tutorial on OpenGL from YouTube, but the instructor used Mac OS so some of the examples are not working for me. An error message showed like

```
glWindowPos2i(x,y); was not declared in this scope.
```

Then I searched it and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108814/glwindowpos2i-was-not-declared-in-this-scope). Now, I did all (i.e., downloaded [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and pasted in my GL folder) according to the answer of that question. But now, the following errors are showing in the error log:

```
X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
```

Please note that, there is a line like `#include <X11/Xlib.h>` in one of the header named `glxew.h`.

What is the solution of the problem?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/3001761, in terms of both your own questions and your suggested edits. You use code formatting where you shouldn't, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use any opengl functions, you have to use the header `<GL/glext.h>` which doesn't ship with windows and is available [here](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glext.h).

As this question is about C++: there is a C++-binding for openGL - GLEW is a C binding. It's quite new, well developed and has a script to keep it up to date: [git repo](https://github.com/cginternals/glbinding)

GLEW adds some basic utility, like the ability to open windows. Afaik, you can use both glbinding and GLEW at the same time.

Comment: I already have ``<GL/glext.h>`` from the link given in the problem for GLEW. what to do?

Comment: Include it in your source files, the function should be available. @manetsus

Comment: I included it before. The described error occurred having the header included. However, As the youtube instructor did not do it with ``glbinding``, It would be difficult for me to cope up with it.